# How to know if a plant has fully grown?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a `BlockBreakEvent` and need to know if the breaked block is a **fully grown wheat seed**.

My code so far is:

```
@EventHandler
public void onBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    String name = player.getName();
    if (e.getBlock().getType() == Material.WHEAT) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Right now my `if` is also entered when the  block is not fully grown yet. So how can I edit this condition to also check for the seed being fully grown?

I am using **CraftBukkit 1.15.2**.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the "age" like this:

```
final Ageable ageable = (Ageable) event.getClickedBlock().getState().getBlockData();
if (ageable.getAge() == 7) 
{
    // wheat is full grown.
};
```

I got the information from [this page](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/checking-wheat-growthstage.427564/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=ff56e690ffff6003aef0bf7e66238b9b6fa87335-1614101935-0-Acj-zO99EElzXC7J_bSUcyiaa_Tp4YmmY-UgnHgiFN1eW9H9tSzHNTu-SxVJ4MG6hTS3FzFbFHi3E62PrK1mpwO33MmXryUx-NmsEZCRj5HlY5TuALCp9b_R54RtWEOBwqFCTt3WhV0f1ftpqHTDe2GZv93Uqh3bVCEjPEfI0p3BVckmrrBb2gkX9mLjYpbbj4pWatfEaikExLQSJNZW3sOv04Be75FTLPqmpgxo71YiUkVtqAmleqRI4PmYXpBiImpOc7FqY9HIaRXx_2qjG4_jm7pIBHN1hY25vwO02f37uM4Si7efORGJXQAX1BjPT9CMvttNjc2CX-tcFFME4x9TP3_k48xhmYeFu8ALZkzP) but wanted to preserve it here in case the link dies.

Comment: Or `ageable.getAge() == ageable.getMaximumAge()`, see https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/data/Ageable.html.

Comment: So i tried that
```if (event.getBlock().getType() == Material.WHEAT) {           
            Ageable ageable = (Ageable) e.getBlock().getState().getBlockData();
            p.sendMessage("It's "+ ageable.getAge());
        }```

But it doesn't return me any message in the chat...

Comment: does it at least print "It's " ? I mean, you had the Block-Type comparison before, so that should still work. Otherwise try `getClickedBlock`